# empty NSIndexSet passed to NSArray objectsAtIndexes, nil or empty NSArray returned?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

As the title states, if I pass in an empty NSIndexSet to `objectsAtIndexs:` method in `NSArray`, does it return nil, or an empty NSArray?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: It would have been quicker to just try it.

Comment: no no... I want to find out the official answer... the suspense is killing me!

Comment: Valid question in my opinion, helps inform how to interpret the documentation correctly!

Comment: @WDUK I'm a huge proponent of devs learning to use the documentation. Far too many questions appear (not this one) because the person was too lazy to scan the list of methods for a class. But the truth is that some of the documentation is less than ideal. Sometimes it is wrong. In some cases it's unclear or ambiguous. For a question as simple as this, two lines of code and 10 seconds of effort would have revealed the true answer. And in the process, the OP would have learned some things. Another few seconds would allow the OP to test what happens for all possible types of parameter values.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I agree, but sometimes there are something that depend on SDK version as well as probably iOS version, in that case, 10 lines of code for testing on a specific iOS version may not give me the universal truth, and may even lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: @hzxu The docs can lead to the same issue. The docs you are reading are for a specific version of the SDK. You may be reading the docs for iOS 6.0 but it is possible the same method behaved differently in an earlier version. And how do you know that an answer you get here applies to every version? This is why a dev must test their app on every version of iOS the app supports. In the end, the running app trumps any answer you get here or what the docs state. Test, test, test. Then test some more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that you will get an array returned, as long as your index set doesn't contain an index that exceeds the bounds of the array, and the index set isn't nil. It'd be cheeky of them to return a nil array if the index set was deemed valid, as that's not what the contract between the caller and the receiver states.

As such, you'll get an empty array returned.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectsAtIndexes:

Comment: Yes, but if the index set is deemed valid, does it just throw an exception instead?

Comment: No, it'll only throw an exception if the set is **not** valid. Which in this case is when an index contained within exceeds the bounds of the array, or the index set is nil (being nil is not the same as being empty!). An empty index set is a valid case, there are sane reasons why this might occur. As such, an empty index set will select zero objects from the array, meaning an empty array will be returned.